# The Mixed-up Colours

Tags: visual

Can you pick the misplaced color that belongs to the other row of colors?  Which one is it?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is

> the middle one in the bottom row

because

> each of the top colors has a hex value which is a permutation of the pairs "ff", "aa", and "55"; the middle color in the bottom row is the final possible permutation of these

Comment: damn it just beat me!

Comment: @jtsalinger-I didnt see it that way. Does the ff,aa and 55 codes represent some kind of colors? Can you explain more ?

Comment: @TSLF the pairs on themselves mean nothing. They give a 6 letter hex code along the format of #FFAA55 (or an anagram off those pairs). I'm not sure how you made the puzzle. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#HTML_color_names) for more

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil-  The above colors were not listed in X11 Web colors link.  I just wondered how  you specify (in RGB : Hex or Decimal) the colors presented in the puzzle.

Comment: @TSLF, the X11 link is just a small sample.  There are $16^6 = 16777216$ possible hex colors ranging from #000000 to #FFFFFF.  Many tools are available to extract hex colors from images, such as [this one](http://html-color-codes.info/colors-from-image/).

Comment: @tilper-nice one, I did it with paint and the codes are in decimals.